# How to position a ring of circles with a maximum ring radius

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, trigonometry, unity3d-2dtools

I'm trying to create a ring of circles, ala:

[image]

The circles have a given radius, `circleRadius`. The ring has a maximum radius, `maxRingRadius`. The number of circles can be any integer number, `circles`, which needs to be calculated, along with the ring's actual radius, `ringRadius`. The circles, when their centers are placed `ringRadius` units from the center of the ring, should be exactly touching, as in the diagram.

Given a `circleRadius`, and a `maxRingRadius`, how can one find the nearest (or next smallest) `ringRadius` which will fit an integer number of `circles`, and then position those circles?

```
    static Vector3[] RingOfCircles(float maxRingRadius, float circleRadius) {
        //int circles = ...; // calculate this?
        //float ringRadius = ...; // calculate this?

        //Edit: Solution. These three lines are adapted from InBetween's GetNextSmallerRingRadius function but Unity3d-ized and without validation
        int circles = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.PI / Mathf.Asin(circleRadius / maxRingRadius)); 
        float centralAngle = 2 * Mathf.PI / (numberOfCircles - 1);
        float ringRadius = circleRadius / Mathf.Sin(centralAngle / 2);

        // create ring of center points
        float radsPerCircle = (Mathf.PI * 2) / circles;
        Vector3[] centerPoints = new Vector3[circles];
        for (int i=0; i < circles; i++) {
            float angle = i * radsPerCircle;
            centerPoints[i] = new Vector3(
                Mathf.Sin(angle) * ringRadius, 
                Mathf.Cos(angle) * ringRadius, 
                0);
        }

        return centerPoints;
    }
`
```

*Note: `maxRingRadius` could just as well be `minRingRadius` or `approximateRingRadius` for my purposes. But `ringRadius` should define the next nearest 'ring' which can hold an whole number of circles.*

---

Solved:
[image: A visual confirmation of the solution]
Visual confirmation of solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, this should do it:

```
 public static double GetNextSmallerRingRadius(double startingRingRadius, double circleRadius)
 {
     Debug.Assert(startingRingRadius >= 0);
     Debug.Assert(circleRadius > 0);

     int currentNumberOfCircles = GetCurrentNumberOfCircles(startingRingRadius, circleRadius);

     //Let's get trivial cases out of the way
     if (currentNumberOfCircles == 1)
         throw new ArgumentException();
     if (currentNumberOfCircles == 2)
         return 0; //trivial solution for 1 circle.
     if (currentNumberOfCircles == 3)
         return circleRadius; //trivial solution for 2 circles.

     double centralAngle = 2 * Math.PI / (currentNumberOfCircles - 1);
     return circleRadius / Math.Sin(centralAngle / 2);
 }

 public static double GetNextLargerRingRadius(double startingRingRadius, double circleRadius)
 {
     Debug.Assert(startingRingRadius >= 0);
     Debug.Assert(circleRadius > 0);

     int currentNumberOfCircles = GetCurrentNumberOfCircles(startingRingRadius, circleRadius);

     //Let's get trivial cases out of the way
     if (currentNumberOfCircles == 1)
         return circleRadius; //trivial solution for 2 circles.

     double centralAngle = 2 * Math.PI / (currentNumberOfCircles + 1);
     return circleRadius / Math.Sin(centralAngle / 2);
 }

 private static int GetCurrentNumberOfCircles(double startingRingRadius, double circleRadius)
 {
     if (startingRingRadius == 0)
     {
         return 1;
     }
     else
     {
         return (int)Math.Round(Math.PI / Math.Asin(circleRadius / startingRingRadius), 0); //There would need to be some logic to make sure input values are correct.
     }
 }
```

To validate the input (defined radii represent a valid solution), you can compare the rounded and not rounded `numberOfcircles` and make sure that the difference is inside a given tolerance. Remember, with `double` you can not check for equality as there will always be a representation error.

**UPDATE** Whoops, I didn't see you were also asking about positioning the circles. Once you know the ring radius and the central angle its pretty straightforward.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! Works great. I already had the code to do the final positioning of the circles in my question so that part was redundant anyway :)